# Track execution time in python

Tags: python-3.x, eclipse, pydev

I want to know how long my code takes to run and have tried using the following code which was found on a different thread.

```
import time
start_time = time.time()

# my code

main()
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

but it does not seem to print the time it takes. I've included pictures of my code since the code is fairly long. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post a minimal working example that reproduces your error

Comment: Please add the code as text formatted as code snippet instead of posting screenshots of the code. In addition, add the error message of the error shown in line 158.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a bug in your code, because this works:

```
def dosomething():
  counter = 10
  while counter > 0:
    counter -= 1
    print ('getting ready to check the elapsed time')

def main():
  start_time = time.time()
  dosomething()
  print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```